# Pivot Table with calculation python

Tags: python, pivot-table, calculation

I have data as below,

```
data = {'Email':  ['gee@gmail.com', 'lee@gmail.com', 'hun@gmail.com', 
                   'kui@gmail.com', 'gee@gmail.com', 'lee@gmail.com', 
                   'kui@gmail.com', 'hun@gmail.com', 'hun@gmail.com', 
                   'gee@gmail.com','kol@gmail.com','gee@gmail.com'],

        'Name':   ['gee', 'lee', 'hun', 'kui', 'gee', 'lee', 
                   'kui', 'hun', 'hun', 'gee', 'kol', 'gee'], 

        'Date':   ['21/01/2020', '03/01/2020', '06/02/2020', 
                   '07/01/2020', '16/02/2020', '09/02/2020', 
                   '07/02/2020', '05/02/2020', '08/03/2020', 
                   '09/04/2020','01/03/2020','03/05/2020'],

        'Amount': [20,30,10,5,10,30,20,40,60,20,10,30]}

data_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

my expected output as below,

expected output

[image]

I have try with pivot table to group the email name and date, but it stuck on part min date, max date frequency and the rest. it is possible to create the table using python. can anyone help how to create the table using python? Thank you

1. column explanation based on expected output:

   1. average = total of amount for each email divide by frequency
   2. frequency = no of date for each email
   3. min date = minimum date in each email and same as Max date.
   4. date different by month = different between max and min date by
      month
   5. output = average * date different by month * frequency

Comment: Please do not use images of tables. We now have a table markdown that allows us to both see how the table should look and to be able to extract the data easily for testing to help us get you the correct answer. Could you please [edit] the question and replace the table with a table markdown? here is a discussion we had as a community on the topic of table markdown over table images: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/403699/12672179

Comment: Hi please show your current attempt at this as well. thanks!